# Remove background color from transparent .png resizes images

Tags: magento2.4.3, resize, png

Can you please help me find and disable code that adds this background color on transparent .png images, when they get resized?

It seems that background color is calculated automatically based on the color or the image. Also color opacity is greater as image dimensions get lower.

Please check screenshots:

[image: product page]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: Magento adds a background color on transparent product png images. Do you know how I can remove transparnecy or make that background color white?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Magento adds a background color by default to the swatches, but if you want the transparency to be removed and add white color instead. You can make following changes in your theme files to make it happen.

In your `app/design/frontend/{Vendor_Theme}/{Theme_Name}/etc` create a file `view.xml` with following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
                <transparency>false</transparency>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
              <transparency>false</transparency>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
                 <transparency>false</transparency>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
                  <transparency>false</transparency>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Also, you might need to run following commands to see the reflection on frontend.

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Comment: These settings do not apply in my case, probably because I'm using "Image optimization based on query parameters" in Configuration > Web > Catalog media URL format